# Angular2 typescript map response to new type

Tags: angular, typescript

having

```
userGroups: IUserGroup[];
this.service.getUserGroups().subscribe(g => this.userGroups = g);
```

getUserGroups returns `IUserDifferentGroup[]` but both `IUserGroup` and `IUserDifferentGroup` have the same fields additionally `IUserGroup` have some more, how to map response to new type ?

```
interface IUserDifferentGroup{
    Name: string;
    Code: string;
    Id: number;
}

interface IUserGroup {
    Id: number;
    GroupName: string;
    Visible: boolean;
    IsDefault: boolean;
    CanAssociated: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this inside subscribe,

```
this.service.getUserGroups().subscribe(g => this.userGroups = g as IUserGroup[]);
```

**EDIT**

As per the comments, modifying,

```
interface IUserDifferentGroup {
    Name: string;
    Code?: string; // <-- made this optional
    Id: number;
}

interface IUserGroup {
    Id: number;
    GroupName: string;
    Visible: boolean;
    IsDefault: boolean;
    CanAssociated: boolean;
}
```

then change subscribe to,

```
this.service.getUserGroups().map((g) => return {Name: g.GroupName, Id: g.Id})
 .subscribe(g => {
  this.userGroups = g as IUserGroup[];
});
```

See if it fixes it.

Comment: I got that one type is not compatible with other, to be honest the IUserGroup has the same what IUserDifferentGroup but also 2 more fields

Comment: I see. Please show both `type`s, in order to see the difference

Comment: If you can make the 2 more fields present in `IUserGroup` optional by using the elvis-operator `?` to those properties in its `interface` definition.

Comment: First of all, they are not same. In interfaces, the property names do matter as well as its types. I can see `Id` and `Name` maps to `Id` and `GroupName`. What does `Code` which is of type `string` map to in the other interface? (the rest of the properties there are `boolean`s)

Comment: I would like to just map Id and name to GroupName